# Word for participating in a war

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am trying to think of a word meaning to "participate" or be a in a war.

---

Example Usage:

> His scars were explained by his **[participation]** in the war."

Comment: How about "fighting"?  (Check synonyms for "fight", "fighting", "combat", and a few others, and see if you don't find one you like.  If not, explain why.)

Comment: The usual idiom is "battle scarred" -- this is not answer, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Service" is commonly used and has the connotation of respect:

"His scars were explained by his service in the war."